# Is there any way to change the Context Menu of a Web browser using Wpf (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, default, contextmenu

I would to change the menuitems in the default context menu provided in the Web Browser Control. I have already tried: webbrowser.contextmenu = mycontextmenu.
Nothing changed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411328/custom-context-menu-for-wpf-webbrowser-control/34602392#34602392

Answer (score 4):

Answer - YES.
There is a setting in the webbrowser control for:
.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;

Setting this to false disables the IE contextmenu, allowing whichever one you set to rule the roots. Simples..

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes.

See [this article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/0764549146_8.aspx).

[Here is another (shorter) article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/advhost.aspx)

Comment: That article is all WinForms. Do you have code that would work in WPF?

Comment: It should work in WinForms and in WPF because it relies on customizing mshtml.
NOTE: Added a new link to another article in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7c283faf-16c8-4b4e-a362-f292e3032abb/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same thing. I read about 5 codeproject articles (they kind of old by the way) but couldn't get the COM interop part right. Probably because I can't program in C++.

But then I found this page http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IDocHostUIHandler.html which seems promising. It contains a c# interface that claims to provide the functionality you want. However I still couldn't make it work all the way, so I'd appreciate if somebody else could contribute to this answer.

Since I don't know how much you are familiar with c# (I'm pretty much a noob by the way), I'll post some extra steps here, using VS2008. Add the Microsoft.mshtml as reference to your project, create a new c# interface, and on top of the interface add the extra 3 "using" statements.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using mshtml;
```

And paste the code of the interface definition. Then make the WebBrowser container implement this interface and all the methods. This is how far I got 'till now. I'm still looking for a way to redirect the browser events to the container.