# How to implement custom context menu in WPF WebView

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm able to implement a WPF ContextMenu on other controls, but it doesn't seem to work on a WebView (Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView).

At the top of the view's XAML, I have the ContextMenu as a StaticResource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="cmBrowser" IsEnabled="True" >
        <MenuItem Header="Get 1 and 2" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Get 1" />
        <MenuItem Header="Get 2" />
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Lower in the view, it is implemented on a Label, and it works as expected:

```
<Label Content="Browser"
       ContextMenu="{StaticResource cmBrowser}"
       Style="{StaticResource WidgetTitleStyle}"
       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
```

However, it doesn't work on the WebView control, implemented as follows:

```
<wbv:WebView x:Name="browser" 
             ContextMenu="{StaticResource cmBrowser}" />
```

I've tried mucking about in the code-behind, but even events like `MouseRightButtonDown/Up` aren't firing.

Any advice on how to resolve?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411328/custom-context-menu-for-wpf-webbrowser-control

Comment: Hi @Andy. Thanks for checking. That post deals with the original WPF WebBrowser control. The one I'm talking about appears to have been ported over from UWP.

Comment: Which is a wrapper around edge.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me to go to Chromium? I can do that :)

Comment: When you click this page. What are you clicking?  Not a wpf control. Put it inside any sort of webview. Same answer.  You're expecting a web page to be wpf. It ain't.