# How to revise paste function of default context menu of WebBrower in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, contextmenu

Recently, I wrote a html editor using Webbrowser component in C#.
in C# , I can use default Context Menu of Webbrowser by setting IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnable as True, or I can assign a new Context Menu for Webbrowser by setting IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnable as false and assign my own Context Menu to ContextMenuStrip of WebBrowser component. But I would like to rewrite paste function and replace paste function of default Context Menu of Webbrowser. I would like to know how to do so. thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238768/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-context-menu-of-a-web-browser-using-wpf-c)?

Comment: Yes, I had seen the related article from code project ,the answer of this post before. and I had completed most of functions of html editor I want(from my perspective :D ). Above is the problem I suffered for months. Hope someone can help.

Comment: WebBrowser control is very limited try http://cefsharp.github.io/api/57.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser.htm or 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238768/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-context-menu-of-a-web-browser-using-wpf-c

Comment: @ Daniel Bahmani Thanks for your reply, I will take a look at it.